# Using two patterns in glob() PHP?

Tags: php, glob

I have a list of files, with different items separated by a hyphen, followed by ".txt". EX: Dog_Cat.txt could be a file, but so could Cat_Dog.txt, and Cat.txt, Dog.txt are also valid. Is there a way I could use glob to return all files with let's say, "Dog_xxx.txt" or "xxx_Dog.txt" using the glob() function? Or is only one pattern legal? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can use braces to combine multiple patterns.

```
glob('{Dog_*,*_Dog}.txt', GLOB_BRACE);
```